# clean up multiple if else statements

Tags: typescript

So I've got this code for the project I am working on:

```
for (const [_, [position2, rotation2, dimensions2, unitType2]] of Array.from(world.query(SNAP_QUERY))) {
    if(_ !== selectedId) {
        const distance = Math.sqrt((mousePosition.x - position2.x)**2 + (mousePosition.z-position2.z)**2);
        const distanceToWidget = 150;
        
        const distance2 = distance - (dimensions2.width / 2 + dimensions.width / 2);
        const distance3 = distance - (dimensions2.depth / 2 + dimensions.depth / 2);
    
        const distanceToWall = ( (RESOLUTION_X / 2 ) - position2.x);
        const distanceToCeling = ( (RESOLUTION_Z / 2 ) - position2.z);

        if (distance2 <= distanceToWidget && distanceToWall > 960 && unitType2 === UnitType.CanvasWall) {
            const leftWallRotation = {rotation: Math.PI / 2 * 3};
            matchWidgetRotation(world, leftWallRotation)
                snapped = true;
                position.x = -RESOLUTION_X / 2 + dimensions.depth / 2 ;

                break;
        }

            else if(distance2 <= distanceToWidget && distanceToWall < 960 && unitType2 === UnitType.CanvasWall ) {
                const rightWallRotation = {rotation: -1.5707963267948968};
                matchWidgetRotation(world, rightWallRotation)
                snapped = true;
                position.x = RESOLUTION_X / 2 - dimensions.depth / 2 ;

                break;
        }

        else if(distance2 <= distanceToWidget && distanceToWall > 960 ) { // right
                snapped = true;
                matchWidgetRotation(world, rotation2)

            const rotationNormal = Vector2.rotate(Vector2.positiveX(), Math.abs( rotation2.rotation ));
            const coords = Point2.moveBy(position2, Vector2.scale(rotationNormal, ((dimensions2.width /2) + (dimensions.width /2))));

            position.x = coords.x;
            position.z = coords.z;                         
                
                break;
        }
        else if(distance2 <= distanceToWidget && distanceToWall < 960 ){ // left
            snapped = true;

            matchWidgetRotation(world, rotation2)

            const rotationNormal = Vector2.rotate(Vector2.negativeX(), Math.abs( rotation2.rotation ));
            const coords = Point2.moveBy(position2, Vector2.scale(rotationNormal, ((dimensions2.width /2) + (dimensions.width /2))));

            position.x = coords.x;
            position.z = coords.z;
            break;
        }

        else if (distance3 <= distanceToWidget && distanceToCeling > 540 ) { // bottom
            snapped = true;
            matchWidgetRotation(world, rotation2);
            position.x = position.x;
            position.z = position2.z + (dimensions.depth / 2)
            break;
        }

        else if (distance3 <= distanceToWidget && distanceToCeling < 540 ) { //top
            snapped = true;
            const topRotation = {rotation: -3.1415926535897936};
            matchWidgetRotation(world, topRotation);
            position.x = position.x;
            position.z = position2.z - (dimensions.depth / 2)
            break;
        }
    }
}
if(!snapped) {
    position.x = mousePosition.x;
    position.z = mousePosition.z;
}
```

It does seem to work okay but I'm wanting to tidy it up a bit, as you'll be able to see there's quite a few if else statements with not a lot of difference between them, so I'm just wondering is there a better way of doing this so there's not so much code?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try using strategy pattern + factory pattern - example - https://gist.github.com/shershen08/232f7518daa8142841c31e061ce91f40 or just find in google

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look

Answer (score 1):

To simplify your logic I recommend to use `Karnaugh Maps`. by using that, you can consider every part of your if as in input, for example `distance3 <= distanceToWidget` > `A` and extract all params, them use Karnaugh Maps to get simplified logic

Here is a video about how does it work:
https://study.com/academy/lesson/how-to-simplify-logic-functions-using-karnaugh-maps.html

And here is an online tool : https://leventozturk.com/engineering/karnaugh/

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'll check it out!